# Как поместить стрелки внутрь swiper?

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, scss, swiper

По макету нужно сделать такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде бы ничего особенного. Я решил использовать swiper т.к. его дефолтные стили похожи на макетные. Я пока просто подключил его и получил следующие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поставить стрелки на картинку?

Моя разметка:

```
<section class="page-section farytail">
            <div class="_container">
                <h3 class="page-section__title fairytail__title">
                    fairy tail
                    <span>Сказочная страна чудес</span>
                </h3>       
            </div>
            <div class="fairytail__inner">
                <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="fairytail__slider swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/fairytail__slider/01.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/fairytail__slider/02.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/fairytail__slider/03.png" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
                <div class="fairytail__contant">
                    <div class="fairytail__container _container">
                        <div class="fairytail__body">
                            <p class="fairytail__text">Каппадокия - сказочная страна воздушных шаров, сырных домиков, разноцветных долин и волшебных рассветов! 
                                                                Сюда приезжают, чтобы увидеть природные чудеса, полетать на воздушном шаре и конечно же сделать миллион красивых фотографий!
                            </p>
                            <p class="fairytail__text">Участников тура ждёт профессиональная фотосессия от лучших фотографов Каппадокии!
                                                                Ведь именно за волшебными фото на рассвете на фоне воздушных шаров сюда приезжают люди со всего мира! 
                            </p>
                            <div class="fairytail__boby-title">Также Вы увидите:</div>
                            <ul class="faurylail__list">
                                <li>Музей на открытом воздухе в Гёреме</li>
                                <li>Ущелье Ыхлара и монастырь Селиме</li>
                                <li>Подземные города</li>
                                <li>Крепость Учхисар</li>
                                <li>Зельве и Пашабаг</li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="fairytail__text">и многие другие достпримечательности.</p>
                            <p class="fairytail__text">Местная кухня — один из поводов посетить Каппадокию, здесь есть рестораны на любой бюджет.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>  
    </section>
```

Стили :

```
.page-section {
    margin: 200px 0;
}
.farytail {}
.page-section__title {
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 128px;
    color: #E2AB3F;
    font-family: "Balqis";
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 100px; 

    span{
        line-height: 28px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: "Roboto";
        font-style: italic;
        color: #000;
        display: block;
        margin-top: -30px;
        margin-left: 185px;
    }
}
```

и js:

```
let mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Optional parameters
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел на офицальную страницу для начинающих библитеки swiper: https://swiperjs.com/get-started/. Там нашел блок с заданием размеров.

```css
.swiper-container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Попробовал. Вроде сработало. Только подберите размер под своё изображение. Можно вместо `width` и `height` использовать `max-width` и `max-height`, как в коде ниже.

```js
let mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Optional parameters
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  }
})
```

```css
.page-section {
  margin: 200px 0;
}

.farytail {}

.page-section__title {
  font-size: 96px;
  line-height: 128px;
  color: #E2AB3F;
  font-family: "Balqis";
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.page-section__title span {
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-style: italic;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 185px;
  }
  .swiper-container {
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="page-section farytail">
  <div class="_container">
    <h3 class="page-section__title fairytail__title">
      fairy tail
      <span>Сказочная страна чудес</span>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="fairytail__inner">
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="fairytail__slider swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/11/10/00/waterfalls-5645361_960_720.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/11/28/10/03/autumn-219972_960_720.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/03/04/00/05/cascade-21749_960_720.jpg" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fairytail__contant">
      <div class="fairytail__container _container">
        <div class="fairytail__body">
          <p class="fairytail__text">Каппадокия - сказочная страна воздушных шаров, сырных домиков, разноцветных долин и волшебных рассветов! Сюда приезжают, чтобы увидеть природные чудеса, полетать на воздушном шаре и конечно же сделать миллион красивых фотографий!
          </p>
          <p class="fairytail__text">Участников тура ждёт профессиональная фотосессия от лучших фотографов Каппадокии! Ведь именно за волшебными фото на рассвете на фоне воздушных шаров сюда приезжают люди со всего мира!
          </p>
          <div class="fairytail__boby-title">Также Вы увидите:</div>
          <ul class="faurylail__list">
            <li>Музей на открытом воздухе в Гёреме</li>
            <li>Ущелье Ыхлара и монастырь Селиме</li>
            <li>Подземные города</li>
            <li>Крепость Учхисар</li>
            <li>Зельве и Пашабаг</li>
          </ul>
          <p class="fairytail__text">и многие другие достпримечательности.</p>
          <p class="fairytail__text">Местная кухня — один из поводов посетить Каппадокию, здесь есть рестораны на любой бюджет.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```